# Excel Date Sequence

Tags: excel, date

Can't for the life of me find this answer.

In Excel, I'd like to have a continuing date sequence.

e.g

I want to include in the sequence the dates corresponding only to Monday/Wednesday/Friday of each week. So lets take next week for instance.

```
08/07/2013
10/07/2013
12/07/2013
15/07/2013
17/07/2013
19/07/2013
etc...etc
```

So to summarise.. just a formula to include the dates for future Monday/Wednesday/Friday's of each week.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a new version of excel (i think it was added in 2010/2011), use [WORKDAY.INTL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/workday-intl-function-HA010354380.aspx):

Let A1 be the first date

Then, A2:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(A1,1,"0101011")
```

And fill that formula down

That string `0101011` tells excel to treat tuesday, thursday, saturday and sunday as holidays (so only Monday, Wednesday and Friday are workdays)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply add an integer to them, of days, respectively, in this case "7", and then extend the list ad infinitum with your mouse, so that it adds seven to the reference list.  I apologize if I am oversimplifying your question.  Anyway, just googled it.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/add-dates-HP003056112.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Put 08/07/2013 in A1 (you seem to be working in DD/MM/YYYY)
In A2 and all cells below put the following:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,A1+3,A1+2)
```